# Error while trying to create a "New" button in Adminhtml Grid table page

Tags: adminhtml, mysql

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i'm working on new custom magento extension.

I've created a custom page in the Admin panel and here is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see i've created a butoon `Create new SMS Rule`, when i click on in i got the following error:

[image]

So now let me show you what i have in the extension files so you can help me out resolve this problem.

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Status extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sales_status';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Send SMS on Order Status Changes');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Create new SMS Rule');
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild( 'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
                $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }



}
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status/Grid.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Status_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('smsnotification_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }


    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smsnotification/smsnotification_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }


    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
          $this->addColumn('id', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('ID'),
              'align'     =>'right',
              'width'     => '50px',
              'index'     => 'id',
          ));

          $this->addColumn('Receiver', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
              'align'     =>'left',
              'index'     => 'Receiver',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('Phone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'Phone',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Date', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'Date',

        ));


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/controllers/Adminhtml/SmsorderstatusesController.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml_SmsorderstatusesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('SMS Center'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('sales/sales');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sales_status'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sales_status_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }

    public function exportInchooCsvAction()
    {
        $fileName = 'orders_inchoo.csv';
        $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sales_status_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
    }

    public function exportInchooExcelAction()
    {
        $fileName = 'orders_inchoo.xml';
        $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sales_status_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getExcelFile($fileName));
    }
}
```

As you can see this page is fetching MySQL data from a CUSTOM MySQL table created by me. Here is the structure of the table named `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`:

[image]

**I have two question about the problem:**

1. Why i get the error when i click on `Create new SMS Rules` and how i can make a page there that have two simple imputs like: `Receiver` where you can place the name and `Phone` and then when you click `Submit` this data should be imported into `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` MySQL table.
2. My second question is: Why when i click on a table row NO "Edit" page is opened. How i can make a simple edit page which will obviously edit the row ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask what module you're running that's giving you that error? It looks a ton better than default Magento errors!

Comment: Here you go: Pulsestorm_Better404

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the button, your error page shows that it has an action of "new", but you don't have "newAction" method in your controller. Regarding edit, you will also want "editAction" in your controller.

Wanted to add this as a comment, but needed 50 rep for that!